# How to access derived class field at runtime?

Tags: c#, dynamic, polymorphism, runtime

Hello guys is there a way to implement the `Equals` method in the base class for derived classes considering the compared field exists only in the derived classes:

```
    public abstract partial class Primitive {
                public abstract PrimitiveKind PrimitiveKind { get; }
public static Primitive CreateEmpty(PrimitiveKind primitiveKind) {
                switch (primitiveKind) {
                    case PrimitiveKind.Bool: return new Bool();
                    case PrimitiveKind.String: return new String();
                    case PrimitiveKind.Char: return new Char();

                    case PrimitiveKind.Sbyte: return new Sbyte();
                    case PrimitiveKind.Byte: return new Byte();
                    case PrimitiveKind.Short: return new Short();
                    case PrimitiveKind.Ushort: return new Ushort();
                    case PrimitiveKind.Int: return new Int();
                    case PrimitiveKind.Uint: return new Uint();
                    case PrimitiveKind.Long: return new Long();
                    case PrimitiveKind.Ulong: return new Ulong();


                    case PrimitiveKind.Float: return new Float();
                    case PrimitiveKind.Double: return new Double();
                    case PrimitiveKind.Decimal: return new Decimal();
                    default:
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }
    }
```

Where every Derived type looks like this :

```
 public sealed class Bool : Primitive {

                    public bool Value { get; set; }
                    public override PrimitiveKind PrimitiveKind => PrimitiveKind.Bool;
            }
public sealed class Byte : Primitive {

                public byte Value { get; set; }
                public override PrimitiveKind PrimitiveKind => PrimitiveKind.Byte;
            }
```

I want the Primitive type to have the Equals  method overriden so  that it would compare at runtime the `Value` field.I need the equal done here for Testing purposes.

Something like :

```
class Primitive{
    public bool override Equals<T>(T other)
    {
    return  `(T)((dynamic)this.[Value])` .Equals(other.Value);
    }
```

Value does not exist in base class -is there anyway i can "pretend" it exists at runtime?Is the `dynamic` word the key here? (I am not very familiar with its usage)
    }

**Usage**:

```
Primitive a=new Bool();
Primitive b=new Bool();
Assert.AreEqual(a,b);
```

Comment: Why would anyone write `Bool b = (Bool) Primitive.CreateEmpty(PrimitiveKind.Bool);` instead of `Bool b = new Bool();`? How is that related to the problem? Try to create a *minimal* [MCVE]. What problem are you trying to solve? What's wrong with the existing approach of the `Equals()` method?

Comment: I am making a custom serializer and i use the Primitive as a common interface for the general workflow.

Comment: This is not a good design, but if you really insist, you can do `return ((dynamic)this).Value.Equals(((dynamic)other).Value);`

Comment: By not good design you are referring to the class hierarchy model or your suggested method?If it is the latter i need something that works.(Testing Purposes only)

Comment: I mean using dynamic this way. Well, it should work (given that all implementations of Primitive has `Value` public property). Another option would be to make `Primitive` generic, like this: `class Primitive<T> { public T Value {get;set;}}` - then you don't need to use reflection (and dynamic is also reflection) to compare that value.

Comment: @Evk Thank you for your answers ! They worked !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a protected abstract property, that your classes would have to implement:

```
public abstract partial class Primitive
{
    protected abstract object ValueObject { get; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Primitive p ? this.ValueObject.Equals(p.ValueObject) : false;
    }
    ...
}

public sealed class Bool : Primitive
{
    protected override object ValueObject => this.Value;
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public override PrimitiveKind PrimitiveKind => PrimitiveKind.Bool;
}
```

This solution causes values to be boxed when getting ValueObject, but it will still likely be faster than `dynamic` and the implementation boilerplate is not very high.

Comment: I didn't use an object because i wanted to avoid the boxing but when i will deserialize i am going to need reflexion so yes i suppose i can use an abstract property.Thank you for your answer !